# Cant unserialize string

Tags: php, serialization

When I try and unserialize the following string:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:19:\"Sales+%2F+Customers\";i:1;s:78:\"Micro+Business+%28less+than+10+employees+%26+turnover+under+%C2%A32+million%29\";i:2;s:13:\"Manufacturing\";}
```

It returns false and I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Error at offset 9 of 158 bytes
```

It was generated by calling `serialize` on an array though and looks valid to me though, I don't understand what the problem is?

Comment: Remove slashes, they should not be here.

Answer (score 0):

The slashes aren't valid in this case, use `stripslashes()`. Demo code below:

```
<pre>
<?php
$x = "a:3{i:0;s:19:\"Sales+%2F+Customers\";i:1;s:78:\"Micro+Business+%28less+than+10+employees+%26+turnover+under+%C2%A32+million%29\";i:2;s:13:\"Manufacturing\";}";

echo "unserializing $x: " . PHP_EOL;

try {
    print_r(unserialize($x));
    echo PHP_EOL;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

$y = "a:3{i:0;s:19:\\\"Sales+%2F+Customers\\\";i:1;s:78:\\\"Micro+Business+%28less+than+10+employees+%26+turnover+under+%C2%A32+million%29\\\";i:2;s:13:\\\"Manufacturing\\\";}";

echo "unserializing $y: " . PHP_EOL;

try{
    print_r(unserialize($y));
    echo PHP_EOL;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}

echo "unserializing stripslashes($y): " . PHP_EOL;

try{
    print_r(unserialize(stripslashes($y)));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
</pre>
```